# Bindings from cursors not showing until after first change detection

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-meteor

when a component first loads bindings aren't display until I force a change detection. Here is the code:

```
export class MyClass extends MeteorComponent {
  list: Mongo.Cursor<Any>;
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.list = MyCollection.find();
  }
}
```

I've also tried this, but it has the same result:

the view loads with no results, until the first change detection happens.

```
export class MyClass extends MeteorComponent {
  list: Mongo.Cursor<Any>;
  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
    super();
    this.autorun(() => this.zone.run(() => {
      this.list = MyCollection.find();
    }))
  }
}
```

Comment: What is returned by `MyCollection.find()`?

Comment: The array of objects is returned.

Comment: Then I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work. How do you bind to the array?

Comment: When I log the variable it logs the cursor in the console. The data does show up eventually in the view, but only after the first change detection. I'm binding using *ngFor.

Comment: For your second using NgZone way, try to change to `list: Array<Any>;`, `this.list = MyCollection.find().fetch();`, see whether it works. angular2-meteor still has some bugs for `Mongo.Cursor`

Comment: I tried that, this time it logs the array of objects not the cursor, but it still does not load the data in the view until after change detection.